# RXJS bufferedAmount / accumulate value / reduce with reset

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a stream of values

```
[ 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1.4, 0.3, 0.6 ]
```

and I want to turn this into

```
[           1         2         1 ]
```

so, we're accumulating the values of the first stream till a whole number is reached (at least 1) and then emit the whole number while accumulating the remaining amount.

It completely boggles my mind and think a solution lies around the corner with switchMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Andrei,

I've used your code and changed it to a custom operator.

```
export const bufferAmount = (
  amount: number
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<number> => (
  source: Observable<number>
): Observable<number> =>
  new Observable<number>((observer) => {
    let bufferSum = 0;
    return source.subscribe({
      next(value) {
        bufferSum += value;
        if (bufferSum < amount) return;
        const nextSum = Math.trunc(bufferSum);
        bufferSum -= nextSum;
        observer.next(nextSum);
      },
      error(error) {
        observer.error(error);
      },
      complete() {
        observer.complete();
      },
    });
  });

ticker.pipe(bufferAmount(1)).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach:

```js
src$ = src$.pipe(publish());

const wholeNumber$ = src$.pipe(
  scan(
    (acc, crt) => (acc | 0) > 1 ? crt + (+(acc - (acc | 0)).toPrecision(1)) : acc + crt, 0
  ),
  map(v => (v | 0)),
  filter(v => v >= 1),
);

src$.pipe(
  buffer(wholeNumber$)
).subscribe();
```

`publish` will make sure that the source is not subscribed multiple times. It's also the short version of `multicast(new Subject())`, which is basically a way to multicast a source. In order for this to work, `src$` must emit asynchronously, in order for the `Subject` in use to register its subscribers(`wholeNumber$` and the other one) properly.

If it the source does not emit asynchronously, you can *force* it to do so by using `src$.pipe(observeOn(asapScheduler))`, which will schedule every notification as a promise.

Let's take a close look to the cb provided to `scan`:

```js
(acc, crt) => (acc | 0) > 1 ? crt + (+(acc - (acc | 0)).toPrecision(1)) : acc + crt`
```

`number | 0` is the same as `Math.trunc(number)`.

In `+(acc - (acc | 0)).toPrecision(1)`:

- when you do `1.2 - 1`, you'd get: `0.199...96`; with `toPrecision(1)`: `(1.2 - 1).toPrecision(1)` = `"0.2"`. `+` will get `0.2` as a number.